# i want to use bar chart istead of sparkline on highcharts in this example

Tags: javascript, highcharts

please take a look at this jsfiddle first

[jsfiddle example of sparkline](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/sparkline)

```
Highcharts.SparkLine = function (a, b, c) {
var hasRenderToArg = typeof a === 'string' || a.nodeName,
    options = arguments[hasRenderToArg ? 1 : 0],
    defaultOptions = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: (options.chart && options.chart.renderTo) || this,
            backgroundColor: null,
            borderWidth: 0,
            type: 'area',
            margin: [2, 0, 2, 0],
            width: 120,
            height: 20,
            style: {
                overflow: 'visible'
            },

            // small optimalization, saves 1-2 ms each sparkline
            skipClone: true
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            tickPositions: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            endOnTick: false,
            startOnTick: false,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            tickPositions: [0]
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            hideDelay: 0,
            outside: true,
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                animation: false,
                lineWidth: 1,
                shadow: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            radius: 2
                        }
                    }
                },
                fillOpacity: 0.25
            },
            column: {
                negativeColor: '#910000',
                borderColor: 'silver'
            }
        }
    };

options = Highcharts.merge(defaultOptions, options);

return hasRenderToArg ?
    new Highcharts.Chart(a, options, c) :
    new Highcharts.Chart(options, b);
```

};

i try to use the concept of having those sparkline between table tags and achieve a chart with more than 2 column on left and right , however instead of sparkline i need bar chart like a picture below

[image: sample data chart]

please help me on this problem ...

Update :

thanks to ppotaczek and his suggestion on changing to bar type i had another problem on the way

[updated jsfiddle with bar type](https://jsfiddle.net/1b8L049u/)

well now i don't know how to make every row to adopt xrow size of 115 . at this moment all bar chart draw the entire cell but 20 from 115 must have different view via 71 from 115 ...

any suggestion to how to put 0 to 115 on the top of the table and adjust the bar charts with that ?

Comment: Show us what you attempted to do, so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `chart.type` to `'bar'` and adapt data in the HTML table.

```
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    ...
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cyuvws37/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.type

Comment: hi and thanks for your time
i really appreciate it and it's very helpful 
but i have other problem in the way 
would you please take a look at the js fiddle update at the end of the question

Comment: Hi @gadfly, Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dfw60jur/